# Electorate badge. Did I qualify for the badge?

Tags: support, badges, voting

For the [electorate badge](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/badges) it states:

> Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

So for my [votes](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/268/guy-coder) I currently (12/8/13) have

627 Votes Cast 
361 question

Now if my math is correct, I have 57% which is more than 25%.

Is so, didn't I qualify for the electorate badge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your math is incorrect.

> Voted on 600 questions

You've only voted on 361 questions. You have not voted on 600 questions, so you don't qualify for the badge.

The two criteria are linked by *and*, so it isn't enough to satisfy one of them, you need to satisfy both.